Notation for combining maps $f : X_1 \to Y_1, g:X_2 \to Y_2$ into the map $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto (f(x_1), g(x_2))$?
Let $f:X_1 \to Y_1$ and $g:X_2 \to Y_2$ be two maps. We create a new map $h:X_1 \times X_2 \to Y_1 \times Y_2$ by "combining" $f$ and $g$, i.e. we set $h(x_1, x_2) := (f(x_1), g(x_2))$.
Does there exist an already established notation for this construction? We could use $h=f\times g$, but this can create confusion in the context of cross products.

The notation $h=f \times g$ is standard. If you know some category theory, it is also "right" in the sense that, if you're working in the category  of sets or topological spaces (say) which I'll denote by $\mathbb{C}$, the function $h(x_1, x_2) := (f(x_1), g(x_2))$ is the functor $\times: \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ applied to the morphism $(f,g)$ in $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}.$
It is always possible to run into conflict of notation - you either make sure it is obvious from context which definition is intended, or change the notation of one of the two. An alternative notation for the cross product is $\wedge$, whereas you could denote the product of two maps by $(f,g).$
